# Configuring NFTY to notify me when a SSH from outside my local ip range

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to be notified if there is ever a successful SSH login into the machine that I accept external connections on via NTFY.  Since I frequently login this machine locally (192.168.1.0/24), I'd like to avoid notifications when the connection is from that range.

I am following the example listed here:
https://docs.ntfy.sh/examples/#ssh-login-alerts

The notifications work correctly but I am trying to modify my script to exclude 192.168.*, my bash is awful and I have been banging my head against this for hours.

I have modified the ntfy-ssh-login.sh to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${PAM_TYPE}" = "open_session" ]; then
        if [ "${PAM_RHOST}" != 192.168.* ]; then
          curl \
            -H prio:high \
            -H tags:warning \
            -d "SSH login: ${PAM_USER} from ${PAM_RHOST}" \
            http://192.168.1.137:8777/alerts
        fi
fi
```

which I expect will not send the alert to NTFY if PAM_RHOST starts with 192.168.  However, it always sends the alert.  I know the value of PAM_RHOST starts with that value because its included in the alert:

```
30/08/2023, 22:12 Priority 4

⚠️ SSH login: --redacted-- from 192.168.1.11
```

That 192.168.1.11 is set by `${PAM_RHOST}`.

I am sure I am doing something silly.

Comment: Why? If your machine is accessible on the internet, you will get alerts all the time - automated attacks **never** stop, and there's new wanna-be script-kiddies pretending to be "badass hax0rs, just like on TV" (usually with kali) all the time.  The constant alerts will drive you crazy.  Just use [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org) or similar to block repeated failed attempts.   Or, if you never need to connect from public IP addresses, just block all ssh connections from outside.  Or allow ssh only from certain subnets, or set up port knocking to temporarily open access to an IP.

Comment: Although I lock my front door I also set my house alarm at night.  I also use fail2ban and logged over 100,000 separate "bans" over the last six months from 12,000 different 'hosts'.  I also run NAT with a different external port than 22.  SSH is the last remaining publicly accessible port.  I need that open so I'd like to be able to be alerted if someone externally successfully logs in because I do it so rarely that it is notable.

Comment: If you want `192.168.*` to be treated as a pattern, I believe you would need to use `[[` for your `if` test as `[` does not seem to support string patterns:  `if [[ "${PAM_RHOST}" != 192.168.* ]];`

Comment: Thank you @GracefulRestart.  That solved the issue and now I am only being alerted from non-local logins.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my comment into something of an answer.

The `[` test does not treat the `*` character as a wildcard/pattern, so the `${PAM_RHOST}` would never match and your `then` expression is always evaluated.

Since you are using `/bin/bash`, you have the `[[` test available which will handle a comparison with `*` as a pattern:

`if [[ "${PAM_RHOST}" != 192.168.* ]];`